# I am still waiting (for/to) results

Tags: prepositions

I want to email my boss that I am still waiting for/to results from users - they need to fill out some form. I am not sure which sentence is correct:

> I am still waiting for results

OR:

> I am still waiting to results

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct form would be

> I am still waiting for results.

Alternatively, you could use the phrase

> I am still waiting to get the results.

Note that "to get" here is used together as a verb, not a preposition as your post was asking.

The preposition "for" can be used to designate a reason akin to "because."

> I am waiting for you.

The preposition "to" can be used to indicate direction, relation, or even a time-span.

Comment: Hello, petryuno. Please don't endorse off-topic questions with answers: it merely encourages more.